# Масштабирование сайта при ресайзе

Tags: jquery, адаптивная-верстка

Как добиться эффекта масштабирования при ресайзе окна браузера, как на сайте http://www.gulfstream.ru/ В чем минусы использования такого эффекта для адаптива? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Да не плюсов не минусов нет, единственное текст становиться меньше - менее читабелен, но не встречал еще ситуаций, при которых я с компьютера смотрю сайт через уменьшенное окно браузера. А так в css у них указаны правила просмотра через планшеты и мобилки вроде. Ничего кроме:

```
setOrderBtn();
$(window).on("resize", function() {
    setOrderBtn();
    if (window.gSiteMode == 3) {
        setCalcWidth();
    } else {
        $(".calc_tab_wrapper").css('margin-left', '0px');
    }
});
```

- не нашел, по resize. Хотя пробежался по их js бегло. Может не правильно понял Ваш вопрос, но более детально ответить не смогу. Буду ждать Вашего комментария